# data getting fetched from server after assigning it to collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

I am new to swift language so not sure how to resolve this issue. Here I am trying to display images using uicollectionview. But I not getting the proper output as it does not show anything on collection view when executed. Need help friends.

**View Did Load Function**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ImageGet()
}
```

**Collection View**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(defectImages.count) // returns zero value here
    return defectImages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.image.image = defectImages[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let largeVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageDisplayVC") as! ImageDisplayVC
    largeVC.imgImage = defectImages[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(largeVC, animated: true)
}
```

**Alamofire to get images**

```
func ImageGet() {                  
    let imageId = Int(details.id!)
    let para: Parameters = ["imageId": imageId]

    Alamofire.request(URL_IMG_List, method: .post, parameters: para).responseJSON { response in
        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                for index in 0..<self.arrRes.count{
                self.imageData.file_name = self.arrRes[index]["file_name"] as! String              
                self.completeImagePath = self.get_image_path + self.imageData.file_name
                    self.imgpath.append(self.completeImagePath)

                    guard let url = URL(string: self.completeImagePath) else {return}
                    print(url)
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                        guard let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
                        print(image)
                    self.defectImages.append(image as UIImage)
                    }
                }
                print(self.defectImages.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try reloading the collectionview after you have successfully added the images to array on success response.

Comment: First after getting the image from alamofire image get method, you need to reload the collection view in the end. After  print(self.defectImages.count) statement- write collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Make sure that you set `collectionView` `DataSource` and `delegate`.

Comment: add collectionView.reloadData() after this line print(self.defectImages.count) at ImageGet method

Comment: 1: Ensure that delegate and data source are set either using IB OR in ViewDidLoad() like `collectionView.dataSource = self` && `collectionView.delegate = self`
2: Reload collection view after all the downloading task is finished. After your line `print(self.defectImages.count)`
Reload like 
`collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reload your `collectionView` once you fetch data from API and please check that you set your `collectionView` `dataSource` and `delegate` from `storyBoard`. if not than write below lines in `viewDidLoad()` before `ImageGet()`.

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

Replace below code with yours.

```
func ImageGet() {                  
    let imageId = Int(details.id!)
    let para: Parameters = ["imageId": imageId]

    Alamofire.request(URL_IMG_List, method: .post, parameters: para).responseJSON { response in
        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                for index in 0..<self.arrRes.count{
                self.imageData.file_name = self.arrRes[index]["file_name"] as! String              
                self.completeImagePath = self.get_image_path + self.imageData.file_name
                    self.imgpath.append(self.completeImagePath)

                    guard let url = URL(string: self.completeImagePath) else {return}
                    print(url)
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                        guard let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
                        print(image)
                    self.defectImages.append(image as UIImage)
                    }
                    self.collectionView.reloadData() // RELOAD COLLECTIONVIEW
                }
                print(self.defectImages.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: self.collectionView.reloadData() is not working now in swift 4, do you have another way to reloaddata in collectionview ?